# g++ produce executable for windows

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, g++

I am using gcc/g++ to compile c/c++ applications - living on OpenSuSe btw.

Is there any way (some option i guess) so that g++ will produce an executable suitable for windows ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for a mingw32 package in OpenSuSE (I know there is one for Debian) or [install it manually](http://silmor.de/39). Then if you have a `configure` script the command line would be something like this in order to have `make` use the MinGW cross-compilation toolchain:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --target=i386-mingw32
```

mingw.org also has a [tutorial on building a cross compiler](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/LinuxCrossMinGW), don't know if that works.

(As an aside: Some websites point to [mirzam.it.vu.nl/mingw](http://mirzam.it.vu.nl/mingw/) containing MinGW RPM packages but it seems like that site is down.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to be running g++ on Windows to get a Windows executable out of the other end.
Check out [mingw](http://www.mingw.org/) or [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Actually, that's not quite true: cross compilation is possible with GCC.

Comment: @Robert P: If it's possible, can you tell me how ?

Comment: Take a look at AndiDog's answer; my comment was more regarding applechewer's remark that you *have* to be running on Windows.  (FYI, mingw is a particular build of gcc that makes Windows executables.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out MinGW Cross and related links:

http://www.nongnu.org/mingw-cross-env/#see-also